# Calculating distance between Point2f C++ OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I recently started writing some programs with help of OpenCV, and i'am in process of writing an app that will track an movment of forklift.
I managed to do all the hard stuff ie. detecting where the forklift currently is , and now I am writing part of the code that will track the forklift  on screen.
The idea is that I calculate point of mass from contours of forklift and I search for most recent and closest point of mass in recent frames , if I find it i draw line between them , and search for more. If i don't find any or they are too far away or too old i create new object ( forklift).

To demonstrate my problem i created a program that does evrything without analizing any frames :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


class Wozek
{
    public:
    string nazwa; //Keeps the name of the object
    int color; // Keeps color
    vector<Point2f> punkty; // Poits of mass detected in frames ( 1st one is the oldest)
    int waznosc;  // How long till the object expire

    int odnow(int x){ //  Refresh the object
     waznosc = x;
     return waznosc;
    }
    int odnow(){
      waznosc = 50;
      return waznosc;
    }

    int klatka(int x){  // Decay the object x times
       waznosc=waznosc-x;
       return waznosc;
     }

     int klatka(){ // Decay only once
       waznosc = waznosc-1;
       return waznosc;
     }

    Point2f dodaj(Point2f x){  // add new center of mass
       punkty.push_back(x);
       return x;
     }

};
bool przeterminowane(const Wozek& value){ return(value.waznosc<1);} // Fuction for deleting decated objects


int main(){
     srand( time( NULL ) );
    list<Wozek > objects; // Create list of objects

while(1==1){

    vector<Point2f> cc;  // New points of mass
for(int i =0;i<5;i++){ // ceating random points of mass

    int x =  (rand()%640) +1;
    int y =  (rand()%480) +1;

    Point2f temp(x,y);
    cc.push_back(temp);


}


objects.remove_if(przeterminowane); // Delete objects that decayed;

    for(int i =0;i<cc.size();i++){ // For each new point of mass
                            // Checking how for the point is from objects last position
                             list<Wozek>::iterator it;
                             double najmniejszy = 0; // lowest lenght
                            Wozek * wnajmniejszy = 0 ; // object with lowest lenght
                            if (objects.size() >0){
                            for(it = objects.begin();it!=objects.end();++it);
                            {

                                Point2f temp = (*it).punkty.back(); // get last position

double wiel ;
                                 wiel = sqrt(((cc[i].x-temp.x)*(cc[1].x-temp.x)) + ((cc[1].y-temp.y)*(cc[1].y-temp.y)));// Wont' work
                                wiel = norm(temp-cc[i]); // Won't work too
printf("%f/n",wiel);
                                if(najmniejszy == 0 or wiel<najmniejszy ) { //if 1st run or wiel is shorter
                                    najmniejszy = wiel; // save smallest value
                                    wnajmniejszy = &(*it); // save ref to object;
                                }
                            }
                            }
//print("%f/n",wiel);
                       if (najmniejszy <100 && najmniejszy!=0)  {
                           printf(" For %d point of mass  object %s is closest at %d\n",i,wnajmniejszy->nazwa.c_str(),najmniejszy); // Print debug msg
                                   wnajmniejszy->punkty.push_back(cc[i]); // Add point of mass to object;
                                   wnajmniejszy->odnow(); // Refresh object so it won't go away
                       }else {  // Couldn't find mass point close enough , create new object
                             Wozek tmp;
                             int color = (rand()%255) +1; // Random color
                             string nazwa;
                             sprintf((char*)nazwa.c_str(), "objects no. %d\n", objects.size()); // Creating name for object
                             tmp.nazwa = nazwa;
                             tmp.color = color;
                             tmp.punkty.push_back(cc[i]);
                             tmp.odnow(); // Setting it fresh and new
                             objects.push_back(tmp); // Saving
                             printf(" For %d point of mass could't find object. Creating new object : %s \n",i,tmp.nazwa.c_str()); // Print debug msg
                       }
    }

    //decay every object
     list<Wozek>::iterator it;
    for(it = objects.begin();it!=objects.end();++it) it->klatka();

    sleep(5);
}
return 0;

}
```

Well the problem is when i coun't distance between two points , varible named wiel seem to always get -nan value , and i see some strage behaviour in 1st FOR on objects , it seems it will enter it even when objects should be empty , that's why i put there if(objects.size()>0 ).

Thx in advance

Writing on Ubuntu 14.04 , Eclipse , Opencv 2.4.9

Comment: One of the big advantages of programming everything in english is that it's easier to get help... (says an inhabitant of a very small country called the Netherlands)

Comment: i guess  wiel = sqrt(((cc[i].x-temp.x)*(cc[1].x-temp.x)) + ((cc[1].y-temp.y)*(cc[1].y-temp.y))); should instead be    wiel = sqrt(((cc[i].x-temp.x)*(cc[i].x-temp.x)) + ((cc[i].y-temp.y)*(cc[i].y-temp.y)));

Comment: Well i rewrote all the comments to english and even added a few  , i hoped it will suffice , guess not ... @Micka  yes that is a problem but it did't fix the issue , I did some more testing and it seems that  new objects aren't created , even  if objects.size is growing i can't retrive values from it

Comment: can you print `temp` and `cc[i]` (or `cc[1]`) before using it? Maybe one of them is NaN already?

Comment: @Micka just a sec ago i found my own mistake   for(it = objects.begin();it!=objects.end();++it);    should't have ; at its end , without it it runs smoothly , thx for help :) , Should i somehow close this post ?